# How to create a sequence that contains a fixed value a specific number of times using XPATH?

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0

I am able to repeat a value, in this case 0, a specific number of times using the expression

```
for $i in 1 to $vMax return 0
```

Assume $vMax is an integer, so if $vMax was 3, the sequence returned would be (0,0,0)

But, is there a simpler or some other conventional way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, there is no such data type as a sequence of integers, so it follows that no expression can produce such a value.

In XPath 2.0 it can be done as `for $x in 1 to $n return 0`.

In XPath 3.0/3.1 it can be done as `(1 to $n)!0`

It's a good idea to tag XPath questions indicating which version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [simple map operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator):

```
(1 to $vMax) ! 0
```

You could wrap either your original for loop, or the shorter version inside of a function and then call that function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:local="local">
    
    <xsl:function name="local:repeat">
      <xsl:param name="item"/>
      <xsl:param name="iterations" as="xs:integer"/>
        <!--<xsl:sequence select="for $i in (1 to $iterations) return $item"/>-->    
      <xsl:sequence select="(1 to $iterations) ! $item"/>          
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:sequence select="local:repeat(0,3)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @MartinHonnen was in XQuery mode :) I've updated with an XSLT example declaring and using a function.